# How can I get main nodes with child data for customize adopter in list View

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Here I'm able to get data under uID. I also wanna have these uids - how can I?

Comment: Check Image Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code (inside your `onSuccess()` method) just call `getKey()` , it will get the parent key of the data you are retrieving

```
String uID = dataSnapshot.getKey();
```